# Convert string with timezone to unix timestamp

Tags: hive

I'm trying to convert a string with a specific timezone (not UTC) to an unix timestamp.

Conversion from strings in UTC works pretty well with `unix_timestamp` function:

```
hive> select unix_timestamp("2018-12-31 23:59:59 UTC", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z") as unixtime;
unixtime
1546300799
```

However, when I simply change the timezone (to another valid TZ name) it doesn't work:

```
hive> select unix_timestamp("2018-12-31 23:59:59 America/Sao_Paulo", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z") as unixtime;
unixtime
NULL
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert a Date String from UTC to Specific TimeZone in HIVE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28508640/how-to-convert-a-date-string-from-utc-to-specific-timezone-in-hive)

Comment: It possibly duplicates of https://stackoverflow.com/q/28508640/10455534 - check maybe you can find answers there

Comment: Yes, its similar, but not exactly the same thing. Function `unix_timestamp` is easy to use when we already have the string in UTC (as in the first example). So convert UTC string to other timezones is straightforward once we get unix timestamp. The function seems to not work in the opposite way, i.e. from a string in a given timezone to a unix timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the timezone itself, my understanding is that there is no direct way to do this using java cannonical id ("America/Sao_Paulo"). The correct format for the date that you are looking for (in full) should be

```
select unix_timestamp("2018-12-31 23:59:59 Brasilia Summer Time", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss zzzz") as unixtime;
```