# PySpark: how to use a MySQL function with JDBC connection?

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am using this query in a MySQL database

```
select *,
    UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CONVERT_TZ(
        SUBSTRING(input_date, 1, 19),
        SUBSTRING(input_date, 20),
        'SYSTEM'
    )) as timestamp
from my_table
```

which is used to convert a sample `input_date` timestamp with UTC offset (eg `2018-12-15T13:48:16-08:00`) to epoch time.

I now need to do the same thing using PySpark and accessing that table through a JDBC connection, but when I try I get the following error

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o62.sql.
: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Undefined function: 'CONVERT_TZ'. This function is neither a registered temporary function nor a permanent function registered in the database ...
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there a better way to do it in PySpark?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this function to connect to the MySQL db:

```
def connect_to_sql(
    spark, jdbc_hostname, jdbc_port, database, data_table, username, password
):
    jdbc_url = "jdbc:mysql://{0}:{1}/{2}".format(jdbc_hostname, jdbc_port, database)

    connection_details = {
        "user": username,
        "password": password,
        "driver": "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver",
    }

    df = spark.read.jdbc(url=jdbc_url, table=data_table, properties=connection_details)
    return df
```

Regarding timezone conversion, this question will help you :

[How to convert a Date String from UTC to Specific TimeZone in HIVE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28508640/how-to-convert-a-date-string-from-utc-to-specific-timezone-in-hive#28528407)

Comment: Thanks pissal, that's what I'm using but my problem is related to using the function `CONVERT_TZ` which apparently is not available in Hive and thus I'm getting the above error. So my question was how to avoid that.